# Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean not working together with Annontaions and HBM mappings

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, sessionfactory

I am working on a legacy Hibernate project.
All the entities have their corresponding hbm mapping files.

The `sessionFactory` is created below way :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingLocations" ref="hibernateMappingLocations"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>         
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" ref="packagesToScanForBaseSessionFactory" />
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="entityInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

Now I need to query a table whose entity(`Student.java`) has annotations configured instead of hbm mapping files.

I tried to query `Student.java` this way in my Dao class:

```
org.hibernate.query.Query<?> query = getSession().createQuery("FROM Student");
List<?> studentList = query.list();
```

This does not work.
It is mindful to note that this way of querying works for all other entities that have hbm mappings and not annotations.

But with annotations, it does not work.

I tried changing the bean definition for sessionFactory by adding value to the property `annotatedClasses` in `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`:

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.Student</value>
            </list>
</property>
```

So finally my `sessionfactory` bean deafinition looks like this :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingLocations" ref="hibernateMappingLocations"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>         
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" ref="packagesToScanForBaseSessionFactory" />
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="entityInterceptor" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

But even with this it giving me the below exception :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: com.Student is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    ... 61 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in XML try doing it programatically. Ive had issues getting the xml correct but have always had success with this (obviously will have to change for your needs) The important part is the package to scan values. This should point to the package that has your mapped entities in it:

```
@Configuration(value="com.database.DatabaseBeanConfiguration")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.database.repos"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "databaseEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "databaseTransactionManager"
)
public class DatabaseBeanConfiguration {
  public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "database_pu";

  private static final String[] PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {"com.database.entities"};

  private static final Properties hibernateProperties;
  static {
    hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior", "convertToNull");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxActive", "50");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle", "10");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxWait", "5000");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property", "50");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cach", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
  }

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  /**
   * Create the entity manager factory bean used in the database connection
   * @return entityManagerFactoryBean
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean databaseEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(databaseJpaVendorAdapter());
    lef.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    lef.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    lef.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
    return lef;
  }

  /**
   * Create the session factory bean
   * @return sessionFactoryBean
   */
  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean databaseSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    sessionBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionBean;
  }

  /**
   * Create the JPA Vendor adaptor bean that is used in the entity manager factory
   * @return jpaVendorAdaptor
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter databaseJpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  }

  /**
   * Create the transaction manager bean 
   * @return transactionManager
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager databaseTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    manager.setEntityManagerFactory(databaseEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing it programmatically instead of XML for me is not feasible mate. These configs are tightly coupled with other modules and cannot be changed

Comment: Can you change `packagesToScan` to be the entity package instead of a reference to a factory? If you cant trying doing `FROM com.Student` in your create query